# Join Oracle table directly to csv file

Tags: r

I have script where I am trying to join data from an Oracle table to a csv file. The Oracle table is HUGE (over 1.8 million rows, which I why I am not loading the table first and then joining to the csv file, instead I am trying to do a left join directly with the csv file) and this is the code I wrote, but I am getting this error:

Error in `left_join()`:
! Join columns must be present in data.
✖ Problem with `PARTYID`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
library(rstudioapi)

output <- crews %>% 
  clean_names() %>% 
  mutate(clientid = str_remove_all(clientid, "[-]")) %>%
  mutate(clientid = str_squish(clientid)) %>%
  inner_join(newcsv, by = "clientid") %>%
  left_join(party <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT PARTYID FROM CURAM.DBO.PARTY"), by = c("partyid"= "PARTYID"))  %>% 
  clean_names()
```

I also tried the code this way and still getting an error:

```
output <- crews %>% 
  clean_names() %>% 
  mutate(clientid = str_remove_all(clientid, "[-]")) %>%
  mutate(clientid = str_squish(clientid)) %>%
  inner_join(newcsv, by = "clientid") %>%
  left_join(party <- dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT PARTYID AS "partyid" FROM CURAM.DBO.PARTY'), by = ("partyid")  %>% 
  clean_names()
```

If someome could help me fix this that would br great as I am sure there must be a way to directly connect Oracle table to a csv file without having to load the entire table first. Thank you!

Comment: *"I am sure there must be a way to directly connect Oracle table to a csv file without having to load the entire table first"* I've got bad news....

Comment: `party <- dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT PARTYID AS "partyid" FROM CURAM.DBO.PARTY')` loads the table. It doesn't really matter if you do it 10 lines before,  one line before, or inline. You're loading the table.

Comment: What you could do is create a table in your database and load the CSV file in the database, do the join in the database, and then pull the result into R. (Assuming you have create table permissions in the database...)

Comment: @GregorThomas I tried loading the PARTY table first in R but since this table is so big, the table does not load and it times out, which is why I was hoping to do a left join with the csv file which only has 6500 rows

Comment: As I said, bad news. See my previous comment for a possible solution. But you can't use R to join to a table without loading the table.

Comment: @GregorThomas thanks for letting me know, that really sucks, do you know any other program that can be used to join csv with a table? Just because I won't have create table permission

Comment: If you don't have enough memory to get the `PARTY` table off of the database, then  you need the database to do the join. That said, 1.8 million rows isn't **that** big. And it looks like you're only selecting a single column from it. Unless that column is a massively long text field, you should be able to fit it in memory unless your computer like 15 years old. Maybe close all other programs to free up memory and try it in a fresh R session?

Comment: You could filter from within the Oracle query like `WHERE Partyid IN {.$partyid}` and use `glue` to assist. That would remove rows before you retrieve the data to memory

Comment: @Cole maybe iteratively. I think [Oracle has a relatively small limit on the size of IN clauses](https://www.optimusinfo.com/blog/include-more-than-1000-values-in-oracle-in-clause), and OP says their CSV is 6500 rows. But they could perhaps break it apart into chunks of size 1000.

Comment: @GregorThomas ah I overlooked that. OP could also create a CTE with UNIONing the IDs together from dual. I don’t have DBA rights so I have had to do a lot of working around although this will be less performant than if the user could create a table

Comment: thanks everyone, I guess the only thing I can now do is what @GregorThomas suggested, which is have a table created in my database and load the CSV file in the database

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comments, this is how we could build a SQL statement to filter in the query as opposed to loading the csv into the database.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

x = tibble(id = 1:10)
interval = 2

x %>%
  {paste(map(seq(ceiling(length(.$id) / interval)),
       function(i) {
         ind = seq((interval * (i - 1))+1, by = 1, length.out = interval)
         ids = paste(.$id[ind], collapse = ",")
         paste0("SELECT PARTYID FROM CURAM.DBO.PARTY WHERE PARTYID IN (", ids, ")")}
  ), collapse = " UNION \n")} %>% cat()

#> SELECT PARTYID FROM CURAM.DBO.PARTY WHERE PARTYID IN (1,2) UNION 
#> SELECT PARTYID FROM CURAM.DBO.PARTY WHERE PARTYID IN (3,4) UNION 
#> SELECT PARTYID FROM CURAM.DBO.PARTY WHERE PARTYID IN (5,6) UNION 
#> SELECT PARTYID FROM CURAM.DBO.PARTY WHERE PARTYID IN (7,8) UNION 
#> SELECT PARTYID FROM CURAM.DBO.PARTY WHERE PARTYID IN (9,10)
```